# YUI Tooltip not displaying on top of Panel

Tags: javascript, events, yui, tooltip, panel

Currently having a problem trying to get YUI Tooltips to display on top of a YUI Panel after it is shown that were previously created.  The problem is is that the Panel cannot be registered to the overlay manager because it would require a TON of code to be changed and tested extending a hard deadline.  The only way *to* get this to work is to setup the Tooltips *after* the Panel is shown.  Problem there is the amount of code changes that would have to be done to attach another function call.  My problem is that I was hoping that I could use the event handling to use `"showEvent"` but I cannot seem to get it to work (I apologize for word count):

```
var panel_obj = new YAHOO.widget.Panel('someID', {
    width: "700px",
    height: "500px",
    close: true,
    draggable: false,
    modal: true,
    constraintoviewport: true,
    visible: false,
    fixedcenter: true 
});
panel_obj.render();

var tooltip_name = 'newTooltip1';
var element_id = 'htmlElementIDToBecomeTooltip';

function createTooltip() {
    window[tooltip_name] = new YAHOO.widget.Tooltip(tooltip_name, {
        context: element_id,
        xyoffset: [15, -15],
        zIndex: 999
    });
}

function successfulScenario() {
    panel_obj.show();
    createTooltip();
}

function failedScenario1() {
    YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(
        'someID',
        "showEvent",
        createTooltip
    );
}

function failedScenario2() {
    createTooltip();
    panel_obj.show();
}
```

The only way I have seem to get it working is by running something like `successfulScenario()`.  I'm coming from a jQuery background so I'm still learning YUI.  I would love to be able to just extend (subclass) YAHOO.widget.Panel's `show()` function to call `createTooltip` but I'm not that much of a guru or I would probably need to change a very large codebase to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using the "container" property for the tooltip config (so the container would be the panel's element):

```
function createTooltip() {
    window[tooltip_name] = new YAHOO.widget.Tooltip(tooltip_name, {
        container: panel_obj.element,
        context: element_id,
        xyoffset: [15, -15]
    });
}
```

This is the quick solution, using the show event and/or extending the class would be nice but gotta run, if you still need help, I'll check back (also check the example that i made with your code http://jsfiddle.net/3GWaM/2/ ).

Comment: This would work if I were using only one function for one panel but the problem is that I am trying to make createTooltip find all elements with classname "tooltip" and then add new instances of YAHOO.widget.Tooltip  but I do like your example and the one from below because it is getting me a greater understanding of how YAHOO defines its library.

Comment: As a side note each widget within the application has many panels to work from and within each many elements that need to be tooltips.

Comment: I remove my previous assertions setting the container was precisely what needed to happen to get my issue working.

Comment: Cool, good alternative solution, perhaps a bit less complex than mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
function createTooltip() {
    var tooltipEl = document.createElement('DIV');
    panel_obj.get('element').appendChild(tooltipEl);
    window[tooltip_name] = new YAHOO.widget.Tooltip(tooltipEl, {
        context: element_id,
        xyoffset: [15, -15],
        zIndex: 999
    });
}
```

This will ensure the that the tool tip div is created inside the dialog box, instead of in the document body, ensuring it does not appear below the dialog box.

Also, if you want to extend the panel class just do the following

```
function MyPanel(el, config) {
   MyPanel.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
   this.createToolTip();
}

YAHOO.lang.extend(MyPanel, YAHOO.widget.Panel , {
   createToolTip: function () {
       // create tool tip here
       this.on('show', this.showTooltip, this, true);
   },
   showToolTip: function () {this.toolTip.show();}
});
```

Comment: Is there anyway this could be attached to the event "showEvent"?

Comment: Yep... you could do something like this (in create tool tip)

this.on('show', function () {/* Call show function on tool tip*/}, this, true);

Answer (score 0):

```
function getPanelIDFromElementID (element_id) {
    var parent_panel = YAHOO.util.Dom.getAncestorByClassName(element_id, 'yui-panel');
    var parent_id = null;
    if (parent_panel) {
        parent_id = parent_panel.id;
    }
    return parent_id;
}
function createTooltips() {
    var tooltip_elements = YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName('tooltip');

    for (var i = 0; i < tooltip_elements.length; i++) {
        var ele_id = tooltip_elements[i].getAttribute('id');
        var name = ele_id.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + ele_id.slice(1);
        var nameArray = name.split("_");

        for (var x=1; x < nameArray.length; x++) {
            nameArray[x] = nameArray[x].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + nameArray[x].slice(1);
        }

        var elementName = nameArray.join('');

        window[elementName] = new YAHOO.widget.Tooltip(elementName, {
            context: escape(ele_id),
            xyoffset: [15, -15],
            zIndex: 999,
            container: getPanelIDFromElementID(ele_id)
        });
    }
}
```